# Adding multiple lines to yaml file based on key

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, yq

I have **sample.yaml** file that looks like the following:

```
 a:
  b:
    - "x"
    - "y"
    - "z"
```

and I have another file called **toadd.yaml** that contains the following

```
- "first to add"
- "second to add"
```

I want to modify **sample.yaml** file so that it looks like:

```
 a:
  b:
    - "x
    - "y"
    - "z"
    - "first to add"
    - "second to add"
```

Also, I dont want redundant naming! so if there is "x" already in **toadd.yaml** than I dont want it to be added two times in **sample.yaml/a.b**

Please note that I have tried the following:

```
while read line; do
    yq '.a.b += ['$line']' sample.yaml
done <toadd.yaml
```

and I fell on:

```
Error: Bad expression, could not find matching `]`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are relatively smaller, you could just directly load the second file on to the first. See [Merging two files together](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#merge-two-files-together)

```
yq '.a.b += load("toadd.yaml")' sample.yaml
```

Tested on [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.25.1

To solve the redundancy requirement, do a `unique` operation before forming the array again.

```
yq 'load("toadd.yaml") as $data | .a.b |= ( . + $data | unique )' sample.yaml
```

which can be further simplified to just

```
yq '.a.b |= ( . + load("toadd.yaml") | unique )' sample.yaml
```

Comment: Is there any way to insert new values but with respecting the alphabetical order? :D

Comment: @MBA Add an extra sort function. i.e. `... | unique | sort`